# Is it possible to create wallposts without having a caption?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Whenever I attempt to create a wallpost that doesn't have the caption set it displays the url of the app where the caption should be. I'd really rather just not have the caption at all, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by setting caption to `<br/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can user `<br/>` or a space `&nbsp;`

Comment: Please learn to use the formatting options to present your answers properly.  Your post contained markup, which the SO software interpreted as formatting commands.  This made your post look rubbish, wich in turn led people to flag your post as Low Quality.